# Unknown column MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database

I'm trying to get a defined number of product that have been sold at least 6 times, but mysql is giving me an unknown column but it is ordering by the same value if the value is taking out of the WHERE clause.

this is my query.

```
SELECT 
ps.product_id, 
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.product_quantity),0) FROM product_stock s WHERE ps.product_id = s.product_id AND s.product_quantity > 0) AS stock, 
SUM(ps.product_quantity) AS vendidos 
FROM product_sold ps 
WHERE 
ps.product_sold_approved_time >= 1419786999
AND
vendidos >= 6
GROUP BY ps.product_id 
ORDER BY vendidos DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the column alias name in the where condition. You can move it as having clause

```
SELECT 
ps.product_id, 
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.product_quantity),0) FROM product_stock s WHERE ps.product_id = s.product_id AND s.product_quantity > 0) AS stock, 
SUM(ps.product_quantity) AS vendidos 
FROM product_sold ps 
WHERE 
ps.product_sold_approved_time >= 1419786999
GROUP BY ps.product_id 
having vendidos >= 6 
ORDER BY vendidos DESC
```

Comment: is this approach better then doing a subquery on the where clause? Like this 

    SELECT 
    ps.product_id, 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.product_quantity),0) FROM product_stock s WHERE ps.product_id = s.product_id AND s.product_quantity > 0) AS stock, 
    SUM(ps.product_quantity) AS vendidos 
    FROM product_sold ps 
    WHERE 
    (SELECT SUM(p.product_quantity) FROM product_sold p WHERE p.product_sold_approved_time >= 1419786999 AND p.product_id = ps.product_id) >= 6 AND
    ps.product_sold_approved_time >= 1419786999
    GROUP BY ps.product_id 
    ORDER BY vendidos DESC

Comment: That depends, for large data set its wise to avoid the subquery and have proper indexes on the columns which will be used properly. But as you asked its pretty subjective and depends entirely on the data volume and using explain plan more about the performance could be analyzed.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this as you are using `alias` in `where` clause. The order of execution of clause is like this:

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

You are confused here that the calculated `SELECT` columns will be available in the `WHERE` clause but this is not the case. Because the `SELECT` clause executed right before hand, everything from the `SELECT` should be available at the time of `ORDER BY` execution.